# Разделение жёсткого диска и файловые системы

Tags: linux, windows, файловая-система, ntfs, ос

Планирую установить 2 ОС на 1 жесткий диск. Насколько я знаю, Windows можно поставить только на диск с файловой системой NTFS, для Linux нужна ext2/3/4. Возможно ли указать для основных разделов диска *различные* файловые системы чтобы установить разные ОС?

Comment: Да, можно. Но раздел, на который устанавливается линукс, лучше сделать расширенным, так как в нем будет еще и раздел подкачки, возможно, home (на ваше усмотрение).

Comment: да без разницы. Какой раздел, какая система файловая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да такое можно сделать. В начале устанавливаете Window , потом устанавливаете Linux. Основной загрузчик grub. Все корректно работает.

Comment: Такой момент еще интересен. На диске есть первые 100 Мб под загрузчик Windows. Что будет с загрузчиком Linux? Я как-то пробовал поставить Mint, в итоге Windows осталась, но загрузчик я потер и туда встал Grub (который Windows не видел), однако тогда я не должным образом отнесся к вопросу деления диска. Необходимо модифицировать загрузчик как это описано [здесь](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-install/7666029#comment-7902461 "linux.org.ru")?

Comment: Модифицировать загрузчик windows не нужно.  Какой порядок действий , устанавливаете windows , далее средствами windows  выделяете дополнительное место на диске (100 - 200 Гб) сколько нужно , При установке Ubuntu или указываете что есть Windows или распределяете свободное пространство в ручную ,и подмонтируете диски windows . В конце устанавливается grub который видит записи для загрузки и в меню предлагает загрузить или windows или ubuntu , там можно настроить что загружать по умолчанию. Для просмотра разделов Linux использую вот такой [драйвер](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd)

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно)

Answer (score 1):

Да, две системы хорошо уживаются на одном локальном диске, к примеру, при установке Ubuntu, можно Выбрать "Установить Ubuntu Вместе с Windows" и установка автоматически все сделает, но лучше делать все "руками", только не забудьте про файл подкачки(вроде 4ГБ просит) пометить как Swap, а основной диск - Ext4,Удачи!